# Ask size of opponents' stack size

Tags: tournament, mtt

Is there a rule as to ask for a chip count of a player?

Meaning, if I am in a hand and can I ask a chip count of the players who are in hand or players next in action?

I know they can just move the chip forward for me to guesstimate, but is there a way for me know the exact chip count? Meaning can the dealer count it up for me the way the dealer does it when a players raises/goes all in.

Comment: Stack size is public knowledge, and it is the duty of the dealer to accurately tell you any stack size on the table upon request.

Comment: @AndrewChin This is an answer, not a comment. You should really post this as an answer because in my experience your posting an opinion, if you posted as an answer it could be voted up and down and commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Las Vegas. Only time you can ask for a chip count is to clarify how much a player has bet. The dealer is not allowed to give you a guesstimate, or a count of a players chips, unless the chips are bet.

You can ask the player to clear their stack, which means to make sure you can see the chips. You can (and should) ask if they have any large chips that might be out of your line of sight.

You can always ask the player, while they are not obligated to tell you, they usually will.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly depends on casino rules. In most places you should be able to ask the dealer for a count.